# Getting an email address for a user logged in through Active Directory with Spring Securitu

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, active-directory

I'm working on a Spring MVC based web application that uses Spring Security to allow users to log in with their Active Directory credentials. I'd like to get the user's email address once they've logged in. I've got the logging in working and now I'm trying to figure out how to get the user's email. It looks like I should be getting that from an `InetOrgPerson` object. I've tried specifying an `InetOrgPersonContextMapper` in the xml configuration as such:

```
<bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg name="domain" value="foo.bar" />
    <constructor-arg name="url" value="ldap://foo.bar" />
    <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
    <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPersonContextMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm trying to get the email in a Controller like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/startProcess.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView startProcess(@ModelAttribute Token token, Principal principal)
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    String user = principal.getName();
    String email = ((InetOrgPerson)principal).getMail();

    logger.info("Got email \"" + email + "\" for user \"" + user + "\"");

    ...
}
```

This was giving me a class cast exception saying it can't cast a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` to a `InetOrgPerson`. I decided to try getting the `Principal` object manually instead of having Spring inject it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/startProcess.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView startProcess(@ModelAttribute Token token, Principal principal)
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    String user = principal.getName();

    Object p = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String email = ((InetOrgPerson)p).getMail();

    logger.info("Got email \"" + email + "\" for user \"" + user + "\"");

    ...
}
```

This is telling me that it can't cast an `LdapUserDetailsImpl` to an `InetOrgPerson`. Shouldn't the `LdapUserDetailsImpl` be an `InetOrgPerson` since I'm using an `InetOrgPersonContextMapper`?

Comment: I understood the result of `getCredentials()` to be a string, namely the user name. Is that not true for your implementation? If so, you will have query Active Directory directly for the email address of the person with that user name.

Comment: Oops I had coped in the wrong snippet. That was supposed to be `getPrincipal()`

Comment: Again, `getPrincipal()` returns a string. You can't use the string effectively as an `InetOrgPerson`.

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree with you there considering the exception is telling me that getPrincipal is returning a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and that I have to call principal.getName() to get the username... last I checked the String object didn't have a getName function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had overlooked the fact that I'm using a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and overriding the `Authentication` with a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` after the user logs in.

I left the `InetOrgPersonContextMapper` on the `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` and in my `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` I cast the `Principal` to an `InetOrgPerson` and store that as the `Principal` in the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`. After that I can successfully cast the `Principal` to an `InetOrgPerson` in the Controller and call `getMail()`.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to change the mapper to org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPersonContextMapper

```
<beans:bean id="inetOrgPersonContextMapper" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.InetOrgPersonContextMapper">
</beans:bean>
```

then use it in your authentication provider

```
<beans:bean id="adAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="mydomain.com.local" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://servername/" />
    <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="inetOrgPersonContextMapper" />
</beans:bean>
```

and then you will be able to cast your principal to InetOrgPerson

```
InetOrgPerson userDetails = (InetOrgPerson)(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! "Change the mapper" was all I need with the same issure.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution works in your case.
You can use LdapTemplate for retrieving an attribute specified in CustomMapper i.e.InetOrgPersonContextMapper class.

1. Create a bean of [`LdapTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.2.x/api/spring-ldap/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html) class

   `<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="com.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">` 
   `<constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />` 
   `</bean>`

   Where contextSource is a reference to an instance of [LdapContextSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/support/LdapContextSource.html)
2. Inject ldapTemplate bean into Controller by auto-wiring
   `@Autowire LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;`
3. Cast Principal instance to [`LdapUserDetailsImpl`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapUserDetailsImpl.html) 
   `LdapUserDetailsImpl ldapUserDetails = (LdapUserDetailsImpl) p;`
4. Retrieve User DN
   `String dn=` [`ldapUserDetail.getDn()`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/userdetails/LdapUserDetailsImpl.html#getDn%28%29)
5. Using a method [`Object lookup(String,ContextMapper)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.2.x/api/spring-ldap/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html#lookup%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.ldap.core.ContextMapper%29) of ldapTemplate instance to get Mapped (mapped by mapper) object i.e. `InetOrgPerson` 
   `InetOrgPerson person=ldapTemplate.lookup(dn,new InetOrgPersonContextMapper());`
6. Enjoy!

**References:**
https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/18/ldaptemplate-java-ldap-made-simple.html#searches
http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: I don't think I can use this method since I'm using an `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`. The documentation specifies that a `ContextSource` isn't necessary when using the `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`.